# How to make laravel factory check for index constraint

Tags: php, laravel, constraints, factory, seed

Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong?
I have an index constraint in table Ratings on keys "user_id" and "place_id". The idea is to have an unique row with that user_id and place_id. My problem is about factory construction. I have this:

```
    $factory->define(Rating::class, function (Faker $faker) {
        $user_id = User::all()->random()->id;
        $place_id = Place::all()->random()->id;
        $used = Rating::where([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'place_id' => $place_id
        ])->get();
//echo count($used);
        if (count($used) === 0) {
            return [
                'id' => $faker->uuid,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'place_id' => $place_id,
                'access' => rand(0, 5),
                'giftshops' => rand(0, 5),
                'location' => rand(0, 5),
                'restaurants' => rand(0, 5)
            ];
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    });
```

Sometimes, with few seeds, it runs ok. But when I try, let's say:

```
factory(Rating::class, 50)->create();
```

I always end up having the respective error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '991b56c8-396b-33c5-8af1-ece8247dbb2e-4b514460-6da9-37ee-b3f8-181' for key 'only_one_user_per_place_rating' (SQL: 
insert into `ratings` (`id`, `user_id`, `place_id`, `access`, `giftshops`, `location`, `restaurants`) values (7f238084-3954-3be4-b3d6-e5f5d15e6b32, 991b56c8-396b-33c5-8af1-ece8247dbb2e, 
4b514460-6da9-37ee-b3f8-1814b6a7a968, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

For debugging issues, I tried to echo the count value and I get values like this in the console:
00000001100010111001010001001000000101101001101111
And then it breaks.

Other weird thing is that, the zero's don't necessarily indicates that the record was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Did a workaround that will suffice my needs.
Gave up on factory and did these routines on seeder:

```
class RatingSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $used = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            $user_id = User::all()->random()->id;
            $place_id = Place::all()->random()->id;
            $new = [
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'place_id' => $place_id
            ];
            while (in_array($new, $used)) {
                $user_id = User::all()->random()->id;
                $place_id = Place::all()->random()->id;
                $new = [
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'place_id' => $place_id
                ];
            }
            array_push($used,$new);
            $rating = new Rating;
            $rating->id = Str::uuid();
            $rating->user_id = $user_id;
            $rating->place_id = $place_id;
            $rating->access = rand(0, 5);
            $rating->giftshops = rand(0, 5);
            $rating->location = rand(0, 5);
            $rating->restaurants = rand(0, 5);
            $rating->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this only works once.
Always keeping in mind the number of "places" and "users" in previous seeders. With few users/places this would be an endless loop.